# Remove everything after domain and http in url javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, strip

I have the full url in a javascript variable and I want to strip it down to the bare url.

For example:

https://www.google.com/hello/hi.php, 
http://youtube.com

strip down to:

www.google.com, youtube.com

How would I do this in javascript?

Thanks

This is not similar to the other links as I am doing this within a chrome extension, therefore the only way to get the url is using the chrome extension api which only provides the full url. As such I need to strip the full url

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

`\/\/([^\/,\s]+\.[^\/,\s]+?)(?=\/|,|\s|$|\?|#)`

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/qJ4vV7/1)

---

Live JavaScript sample:

```js
var regex = /\/\/([^\/,\s]+\.[^\/,\s]+?)(?=\/|,|\s|$|\?|#)/g;

var input = "https://www.google.com/hello/hi.php, http://youtube.com,"
          + "http://test.net#jump or http://google.com?q=test";

while (match = regex.exec(input)) {
    document.write(match[1] + "<br/>");
};
```

---

Hope it helps

Comment: I have no idea why this has been downvoted so much, it works perfectly and is exactly what I need. Thanks. I will accept it in 5 mins when I am able to

Comment: @KVohra95. It was downvoted because my first attempt of solving was really bad...

Comment: @Jonny5. Thank you for that. I've updated.

Comment: im struggling on implementing this regex in javascript. I know how to do it in php but would you be able to help? How would i apply this regex to a string in javascript and return the part of the string that is valid? Thanks

Comment: @KVohra95. I've updated with a javascript example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes! Perfect, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the global `window.location.hostname` variable, and it will give you this information.

Comment: this would be fine but I am doing this via a chrome extension and therefore I needed to strip the full url since I do not have access to window.location.hostname. Thanks for the suggestion however

Comment: Next time try to specify your dev environment in the question. Then you won't receive a bunch of close flags.

Answer (score 0):

While parsing with regular expressions like the other answers suggest is possible, a better approach would be to use the `URL()` object/API ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)).

```js
const a = "https://www.google.com/hello/hi.php";
const hostname = new URL(a).hostname; // "www.google.com"
```

Apart from being arguably "cleaner", another advantage is that if the underlying parsing logic is incorrect, it is a (potentially security) bug in the browser, not your code, and will be likely fixed without your effort.